# How do I get a unicorn in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I heard from somebody that there are unicorns in Minecraft. Is this true? If so, how do I get one?

Answer (score 13):

**No.** There are no unicorns in Minecraft. The closest thing Minecraft has is horses, which can be found in plains biomes.

Comment: What if you craft a carrot and horse together?

Comment: @NickT If you can figure out how to fit a horse in that little crafting table, by all means, test it out and let me know.

Comment: A sword might work, as [seen here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHMT8b1hOdM#t=57s).

Comment: @NickT I remember Skyrim making them with arrows.  Might work in Minecraft too.

Answer (score 2):

Mo Creatures mod. It has unicorns and a ton of other wicked awesome animals.

Answer (score -1):

The closest thing to a Unicorn in Minecraft would be to install a custom texture pack, where the horses looks like :Unicorns:  Do I know of one? Not yet.

Comment: [Here you go](http://www.minelittlepony.com/wiki/Main_Page)

Comment: Hahaha! Oh man, who has time to develop this.

Answer (score -3):

There is a mod for it.It's called the ore spawn mod.They live in the chaos demention.Edit my answer if you know any others.

Comment: At least tell me why its bad.

Comment: before your edit you mention a mod but don't name it, if you couldn't remember the name then you should not have posted an answer but instead a comment, even after your edit "ore spawn mod" is more of a description than a name and it'll be better if you posted a link to it. also your final sentence shouts out you want your answer to be a list of mods that add unicorns but you don't want to do the work to compile the list yourself but instead everyone else should in which case the answer should have been posted as a community wiki